# VBscript, which will MAKE a local user change their password at next login

Tags: vbscript, local, change-password

Ok, so I have been going at this forever now and I am finding no answers to this that actually work. So, I am trying to create a Script which will make a local user change their password when they next logon. I have looked and looked and looked, but nothing helps. Though I feel like I’m close but missing something. Now I will say I am very, very new to scripting in general so sorry if I seem dumb, but I’d love the help. Also, I am using Windows 10 (not sure if that will make a difference). I am also creating this for a school assignment and I did ask my teacher for a hand, but it’s been a week sense I have heard anything. Thank you!

Now here is what I have:

```
strComputer = "LAPTOP-56BDJGPQ"
Set usr = GetObject("WinNT://LAPTOP-56BDJGPQ/Guest,user")
usr.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
usr.SetInfo
```

Now, I know that maybe where it says /Guest,user might be incorrect but I have also tried using my account which is the admin, even that seem to do nothing.

Here is what happens when I run it (now, I do run everything through command prompt)

```
c:\Comp230>cscript USER_Logon_reset.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


c:\Comp230>
```

Now this to me shows it ran, but when I go to test to see if it worked well nothing happens.

I will say I have tried other ways of scripting this part like replacing usr.Put to objUser.Put, etc. I would love any input I could get because this is frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [Password Never Expires](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746537(v=vs.85).aspx) flag is set, you need to delete it first to expire the password.

Try the following instead.

```
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &H10000 ' 65536

Set usr = GetObject("WinNT://LAPTOP-56BDJGPQ/JohnDoe,user")
currentFlags = usr.Get("UserFlags")

'check if "password never expires" flag is set. if so, remove it
If currentFlags And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
    newFlags = currentFlags - ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    'setting new flags
    usr.Put "UserFlags", newFlags
End If
usr.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
usr.SetInfo
```

You may also need to remove the [User Cannot Change Password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746399(v=vs.85).aspx) flag if it's set.

Comment: That worked. Now another thing i am trying to do is to make it so the user after 30 days has to change their password. is there a way to do that for a local user or only if you have access to active directory?